# Joining Keys Issue

Tags: sql, hana

I am creating HANA View where I have to join two tables and my base table will Table 2 and show Item as per Qty.

Table 1

```
Bill No  | Item    | Qty |
BILL001  | ITEM001 | 1   |
BILL001  | ITEM002 | 3   |
BILL001  | ITEM002 | 2   |
```

Table 2

```
Bill No  |BarCode | Qty |
BILL001  |BarC01  | 1   | 
BILL001  |BarC02  | 1   |
BILL001  |BarC03  | 1   |
BILL001  |BarC04  | 1   |
BILL001  |BarC05  | 1   |
BILL001  |BarC06  | 1   |
```

Required Result

```
Bill No  |BarCode | Qty | Item    |
BILL001  |BarC01  | 1   | ITEM001 |
BILL001  |BarC02  | 1   | ITEM002 |
BILL001  |BarC03  | 1   | ITEM002 |
BILL001  |BarC04  | 1   | ITEM002 |
BILL001  |BarC05  | 1   | ITEM003 |
BILL001  |BarC06  | 1   | ITEM003 |
```

Important Note - In Table 2 Qty always will be one.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what the *rule* for your join should be. Could it be that you want to have `Item` joined to `Table 2` as often as the value of `Qty` in `Table 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t2.*, t1.item
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by bill_no order by barcode) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 left join
     (select t1.*, sum(qty) over (partition by bill_no) as running_qty
      from t1
     ) t1
     on t2.seqnum > t1.running_qty - qty and
        t2.seqnum <= running_qty;
```

This assigns the items arbitrarily, because there is no information for assigning them otherwise.

Comment: My bad in table 1 last item is ITEM003.

Comment: @ArunGupta . . . Does something about your comment suggest that this answer doesn't work?  Also, you should edit the question for a small change like that.